# How can I find the last 0 on an array in nasm?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm writing code to find the last 0 on an array.

Basically I need to move a new value on the "top" of each array, if it has only zeros it puts it at the end and if it finds other value it puts it on the last 0 (I'm treating my arrays as piles).

So far my subroutine works fine for the most part but sometimes it rewrites a value that I don't want (instead of getting the first value different from 0 it takes the next one). Here's the code I've been using to get the "top" of the array.

```
TOP:
    xor ecx,ecx
    xor ebx,ebx
TOP_FOR:                    
    mov bx,word[eax+ecx*2]   ;eax has the pointer of the array
    cmp ecx,n                ;n is the array's length
    je END_TOP
    inc ecx
    cmp bx,0
    je TOP_FOR
                    ;here i get the direction of the first value different
END_TOP:            ;from 0 but in my code i need the last 0, so
    dec ecx         ;i decrease ecx (result of this subrutine)
    ret
```

For example, 
If I put an array with 0,2 I expect `ecx = 0`, but with that input actually get 1.

- With the array 1,2 I get 0 (which is what I want)
- with the array 0,0 I get 1 (what I want, again)

Edit: tried starting the loop on n-1 and it's giving me even weirder results.

```
TOP:
    xor ecx,ecx
    ;xor ebx,ebx
    mov ecx,n-1
TOP_FOR:
    ;mov bx,word[eax+ecx*2]
    cmp word[eax+ecx*2],0
    je FIN_TOPE
    dec ecx
    cmp ecx,0
    jne TOP_FOR

END_TOP:

    ret
```

Comment: Your updated code doesn't run the loop body for `i=0`, so it never looks at the first element.  That's why I used `dec ecx / jge` in my answer; it only leaves the loop after ECX becomes `-1`.  Also note that `dec` sets flags, you don't need a separate `cmp` with 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is totally backwards.  **Your `cmp`/`je` loop condition leaves the loop when you find the first non-zero.**  (And you've already incremented ECX after loading, but before checking it).

So after your loop, ECX = index of the element *after* the first non-zero element.

**You at least 2 options:**

- remember the last-seen 0 in another register, and use it at the end of the loop
- loop *backwards*, starting with ECX = n-1, and exit the loop on the first zero.  (Or on `dec ecx` producing 0.)

One of these is obviously more efficient and easier than the other. :P

I'll leave it up to you to solve the off-by-1 problems, but probably you want to have the `ecx < n` or `ecx >= 0` check at the bottom of the loop, e.g. `dec ecx / jge TOP_FOR`.  i.e. a `do{}while(--i)` loop.

---

Also, normally EBX is a call-preserved register.  You don't need to use it at all, though.  `cmp word [eax + ecx*2], 0` works fine.

Also in your current code, you read 2 bytes past the end of the array.  potentially faulting if it was at the end of a page.  (You don't use it, though, so it's not a correctness problem other than that.)  You use ECX as an index *before* checking if it's too large!  That problem goes away if you just use a memory, immediate `cmp`.

Also, normally a pointer-increment is more efficient.  After the loop you can subtract and right-shift to get an index.